# Sending Data with Ajax & Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

### **EDITTED WITH FIXES - PROBLEM RESOLVED**

**Context**: I'm trying to create a page where clicking an image changes the user's preferences on the server. Trying to use ajax to send the information without refreshing the page, and Jquery to trigger the post.

**Problem**: Nothing seems to be posting. It seems the ajax isn't posting the data to the data.php file.

**Intended action**: *When image is clicked, the id of the parent is posted in the game column for that user.*

**header.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pickteam").click(function() {
        var game = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
     $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: 'data.php',
            data: {game: game},
            type: 'post',
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="col-md-3 team1 otherteam" data-id="m004">
    <button class="pickteam">
        <img src="http://img.fifa.com/images/flags/4/bra.png" alt="Brazil">
    </button>
    <span class="country">BRAZIL</span>
</div>
```

**data.php**

```
$game = $_POST['game'];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO choices (user, game) VALUES ('12345', '$game')");
```

Thanks in advance of any and all help.

Comment: Although well formed, this is not a question, and you don't explain what exactly is your problem. Please complete so that we can help you :-) Any explanation (is the request issued ? where is exactly the problem ? do you get any error message ?) would be of help

Comment: and what ? what is the error ?

Comment: Problem: Nothing seems to be posting. It seems the ajax isn't posting the data to the data.php file.

Comment: Still nothing. Would the fact that I'm running this on my local server have any effect? The problem is that the data is not being passed to the data.php form.

Comment: @JamesPatrick no its nothing do with local server. Can you see any error in console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var game = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');` to get the value from parent div

And remove extra comma from your ajax function near `type : "post",`, so the final code should be :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".pickteam").click(function() {
            var game = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
         $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'data.php',
                data: {game: game},
                type: 'post'
            });
        });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Turns out I forgot the document ready wrapper and this fixed the attr('data-id') problem as well. Thanks Rakesh!

Comment: @JamesPatrick, so finally '$(document).ready()' was the issue?

Comment: And the assignment of the variable. It wasn't calling data-id initially. The two fixes combined made the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're not getting your data id right because your jQuery code should be `var game = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');`, so to put it all together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".pickteam").click(function() {
        var game = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
     $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: 'data.php',
            data: {game: game},
            type: 'post'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, or var game = $(this).parent().data().id;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
var game = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
```

To get the value of the data-id attribute.
It's not clear what exactly goes wrong. Could you provide more details on where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your code inside Document ready wrapper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pickteam").click(function() {
        var game = $(this).parent().data('id');
     $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: 'data.php',
            data: {game: game},
            type: 'post',
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```